# How to unregister an intent that was invoked from a destroyed activity?

Tags: android, android-intent

My design requires that I kill the get_configuration activity (Activity1) once the second_activity is running. However, when I hit the BACK button from the second_activity (Activity2), I get the following error:

"E/ActivityThread(2156): Activity com.test.Test has leaked IntentReceiver  that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?"

I'm new to Android, all my research mentions unregistering intent receivers - but I'm not using an intent receiver, just the intent to pass the bundle to the second_activity.

How do I unregister my intent from a destroyed activity? Here is the code I am using:-

### Activity1 class:

```
SetupActivity() {
   ...
     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class);
     intent.putExtra("width", intWidth);
     intent.putExtra("height", intHeight);
     finish(); // kill this activity
     startActivity(intent); // start Activity2
```

}

### Activity2 class:

```
OnCreate() {
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
 if (extras != null) {
     width = extras.getInt("width");
     height = extras.getInt("height");
  }
}
```

Comment: u have try after commenting `finish();` in Activity1 ?

Comment: That was my initial guess, but I still see the issues after removing the finish();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a Java class. It is named `com.test.Test`. In there, you have called `registerReceiver()`, yet failed to call `unregisterReceiver()` before it was destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you registering an intentreceiver in activity 2?

If you you need to register the IntentReceiver in the onResume and unregister it in the onPause.

You need to register an IntentReceiver if an only if you're listening for a broadcast, you do not need to register an IntentReceiver to start activity2 from activity1. Also you do no need to destroy the intent that's passed from Activity1 to Activity2 as that remain during the lifecycle of the Activity only.

Comment: Thanks, no I have not registered an Intent Receiver in Activity2. I just use the Bundle to get the intent extras.

Comment: Is actiivty2 com.test.Test or is that Activity1, it appears there's an IntentReceiver registered in the activity Test